# Query for SUM of grouped COUNT in SQL Query table

Tags: sql, postgresql, group-by, rollup

Please take this as an example where my primary table is

```
ID Name 
-- ------- 
1 Alpha 
2 Beta 
3 Beta 
4 Beta 
5 Charlie 
6 Charlie
```

as there is duplication in Name column. Resultant Table after grouping them by name, with count column is -

```
Name Count 
------- ----- 
Alpha 1 
Beta 3 
Charlie 2 
SUM 6
```

Here SUM is taken out as separate row of all the resultant COUNT column, I am trying to get SUM of all the rows from the resultant Count function from primary table but as separate query for SUM unlike separate row

My table has 2 fields Roles and User_Id.
I have already tried Below query

```
select orl.role , 
       SUM (orl.role) as "No of Users" 
from org_user_roles orl 
group by orl.role
```

Comment: The error message is clearly complaining that you tried to sum the `user_id` column, which is of type `uuid` for which no `sum` function exists. In the SQL in your question body, you sum the `role` column instead - is that what you wanted to do?

Comment: Trying to get sum of the resultant column "count" value for each role.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to count rows (users) for each role, use the [`COUNT` aggregate function](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/12/functions-aggregate.html) - not `SUM`:

```
select "role", count(*) as "No of Users" from org_user_roles group by "role";
```

To get the sum of these grouped counts - which is just the overall row count - use:

```
select count(*) as "Sum" from org_user_roles;
```

Comment: After getting user count, how to get sum of the resultant count value?

Comment: The count already is a sum? Unclear what you mean. If you want to sum the user counts of all roles, that makes no sense - that's just the number of rows in the `org_user_roles` table, which you get by `select count(*) from org_user_roles;` (without any grouping). If you need something else, please post some example data and the expected  results.

Comment: I am trying to get SUM of all the rows of the resultant column count.

Comment: The sum of the counts of the groups is the count of the ungrouped rows. Please provide an example in your question if this code does not do what you want.

Comment: Please take this as an example where my primary table is -ID  Name
--  -------
1   Alpha
2   Beta
3   Beta
4   Beta
5   Charlie
6   Charlie       as there is duplication in Name column. Resultant Table after grouping them by name, with count column is  -  Name     Count
-------  -----
Alpha     1
Beta      3
Charlie   2
SUM       6 -  Here SUM is taken out as seperate  row of all the resultant COUNT column, i am trying to get SUM of all the rows from the resultant Count function from primary table but as seperate query for SUM unlike seperate row.

Comment: Please [edit your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/58404833/edit) to add the example data, where you can format in a readable way

Comment: Sorry, I didn't really understand your comment. Please clarify: do you want the sum of all counts as a separate row in the grouped query, or do you want to make a separate query for the sum of all counts alone?

Comment: I want to make a separate query for the sum of all the counts alone not as a separate row. Thank you, i will make the changes in the question.

Comment: That's what `select count(*) from org_user_roles;` will achieve, yielding the expected result `6` in your example

Answer (score 0):

i think this is a `string` column with numerical values. So need to `cast` it to `int` before performing the `sum()` operation

```
select  orl.role, 
    sum(orl.user_id::int) as "No of Users" 
from org_user_roles orl 
group by orl.role
```